# Detecting launch from home screen with PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am about to start exploring PWA and can't understand the fact of tracking the "source" which user came from;

Can we detect the fact that pwa app is runned by the web browser from links, google searching, etc, or user install the app on homescreen and launch from there?

I just need to know that "we can" or "it's impossible" to figure out is PWA technology suitable for a project.

Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach I've seen is to include a specific URL parameter as part of your `start_url` value in the web app manifest. When your installed PWA is launched, that URL parameter will be present in your traffic analytics.

E.g. `start_url: '/index.html?utm_source=homescreen'`

Just make sure that if you have a service worker that serves your web app's HTML from the cache it's able to deal with that extra URL parameter. If you do a `caches.match('/index.html?utm_source=homescreen')`, for instance, that won't result in a match if your cache key is `'/index.html'`. You could do `caches.match('/index.html?utm_source=homescreen', {ignoreSearch: true})` in that scenario instead.